# swift efficiently reusing classes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a game using swift and spritekit. I have a class called `Utilities` that has a bunch of generic functions that get used around the game. Currently I create a new instance of the `Utilities` class in my single game scene, and then pass the references though to other classes like so

```
self.util = Utilities()
self.player = Player(util: self.util)
self.monster = Monster(util: self.util)
```

I'm doing this so that i only create one instance of the class, but the more i go on the more  just want to make a new instance of utilities in each class i need it in. Is there a downside to this? Is it more efficient to just have the one instance created and pass it around or will it not make a difference if i have say 5 or 6 instances?

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate the `Utilities` class? You can just keep class level functions in that file and call them from where ever you want.

Comment: Swift is not Java. You don't need a class to wrap generic functionality. You can just have them as global functions. (I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you shouldn't need to instantiate your Utilities class. You can write public functions in it and call those methods from where ever you like.

If you need to instantiate your class and would like to keep a single instance, you should go for singleton. You can create a singleton like

```
class Utilities {
    static let sharedInstance = Utilities()
}
```

And you can get the instance by calling `Utilities.sharedInstance`

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh i gotcha. I'm still fairly new to swift, but adding the static keyword lets me use `Utilities.whatever()` which is what i want. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Here's a post that goes into detail on this topic. http://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

Answer (score 0):

If the `Utilities` instance does not hold any specific state, then you probably don't need a class at all. Just define your functions as public global functions.

Swift is *not* Java. Functions can stand on their own. They don't need to be attached to a class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html